# Flot Chart : Doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, flot

I try different solutions for this problem such as:

> - Use a modified html5shiv. The html5shiv script adds the ability to add HTML5 tags into older versions of Internet Explorer.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

> - Use excanvas to provide a fallback to the

```
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/excanvas.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Nothing helps. Get an error:

> Canvas is not available. If you're using IE with a fall-back such as
>   Excanvas, then there's either a mistake in your conditional include,
>   or the page has no DOCTYPE and is rendering in Quirks Mode.

Some other solutions?

---

all scripts above i include before including flot.js.

Changing of DOCTYPE also doesn't help.

---

Source of Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- common styles & scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/custom-fonts.css?v=201306210000" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/styles.css?v=201306210000" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/common.js?v=201306211714"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/control-custom-alert-scripts.js?v=201306211714"></script>
    <!-- custom styles & scripts -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/localization/en/JsMessages.js?v=201306210000"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ad-gallery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.effects.blind.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.selecttime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.number_format.js?v=201208031818"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Content/css/jquery.tree/jquery.tree.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Content/css/jquery.ad-gallery.css" />


    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <style>
        /*body {background:none}*/
        /*
        #global-wrap .nav, #global-wrap .footer, #global-wrap .content-wrap, #global-wrap .user-nav{display:none}
        #oldb-block {display:block; margin: 0 auto;}
        */
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.defaultText.js?v=201208031818"></script>        
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/excanvas.min.js"></script>    
    <![endif]--!>

    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link href="/Content/css/ie7styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link href="/Content/css/ie8styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link href="/Content/css/ie9styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <title>

    Listing Stats


    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta content="Viewed Listings Meta" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="commercial real estate marketing, commercial real estate professionals" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/styles-ui2.0.css?v=201310240000" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.selection.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/control-chart-scripts.js"></script>


    <!--[if IE]>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            // Add Default Text to inputs
            $(function () {
                $.defaultText({
                    css: 'default-text' 
                });
            });    
        </script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CustomError() {
            $('div.validation-error').each(function () {
                var error = $(this, 'span').text();
                if (error == '')
                    $(this).hide();
                else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            CustomError();
            $('button').click(CustomError);
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({
            // Disable caching of AJAX responses
            cache: false
        });

        var noAjaxBlock = false;

        $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                if (!noAjaxBlock) {
                    startBlockUI();
                } else {
                    noAjaxBlock = false;
                }
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                if (!noAjaxBlock) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                }
            });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you try to set your `DOCTYPE` ?

Comment: @twister0k this i don't try. How it can help me?

Comment: Error which you are received said that `...the page has no DOCTYPE and is rendering in Quirks Mode.` I guess, that it makes sense.

Comment: @twister0k :( this doesn't help.

Comment: Which "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" in your IE browser?

Comment: Maybe [some of this solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208062/using-flot-with-bootstrap-ie8-incompatibility) can helps

Comment: @twister0k well, document mode = 8 and user agent string = IE8

Comment: @user3296938 Please show us your actual full HTML.  There is almost certainly something wrong with your doctype or the way you're including excanvas.  Are you using actual IE8, or a newer version in an older browser mode?

Comment: @DNS add source, not all, but main as i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem the other day, [this blog post](http://biostall.com/how-i-got-jquery-flot-graphs-to-work-in-ie8) saved me with these instructions:

> 1. Use the excanvas.js (or smaller excanvas.min.js) that is included from within the Flot repository. This one differs from others I believe and contains the necessary amendments to make it work
> 2. Include the excanvas JavaScript file before you include the Flot JavaScript file(s).

Make sure Tools->Developer Tools->Browser Mode is set to "IE8" as well!

Comment: Well, i accept your answer, but my problem was in emulation of IE8 from IE11. In Original IE8 - all is good.

Comment: @user3296938 That's why I was asking about using real IE8 versus an emulated mode.  The #2 cause of this problem (after using the wrong DOCTYPE) is setting IE8 mode on a more recent IE.  This prevents the [if lte IE 8] from including Excanvas (since the IE version is greater than 8), yet there is no canvas tag (since you're using the older render mode).

Comment: in my case, it does work, but very very slow. It took IE8 a few minutes to finally display the charts